# Section number and heading

Tags: beamer, sectioning

For a basic presentation as follows, how to get the section number and heading? Though this is under beamer what I want to get is basically a presentation in article type. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Basic presentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{beginning}
\frame{This is my first slide}

\section{The great part}


This is my second slide}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a sketch how the result should look like?

Comment: @samcarter, I google and found one: http://www.win.tue.nl/~rvhassel/Onderwijs/Old-Onderwijs/2DE08-1011/ConTeXt-OWN-FA-201209-Bib/Lp-complete/605lec4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\usetheme{Frankfurt}` theme to see the **section** Name. There is a lot of themes available for beamer, just google it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}    % Frankfurt, boxes, Luebeck, Boadilla, AnnArbor, Antibes
\usecolortheme{crane}

\title{Basic presentation}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{beginning}
\begin{frame}{frame title 1}{frame subtitle 1}
    This is my first slide
\end{frame}

\section{The great part}
\begin{frame}{frame title 2}{frame subtitle 2}
    This is my second slide
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```